How to use Pkl configuration and Maven?
I am building a Java project and would like to use the Pkl configuration tool. I planned to use the generated Java code from Pkl and use it inside my project as regular classes. Also, I am using Maven. I came across the exec-maven-plugin to run the Pkl jar and generate Java code for me but I can't configure it properly.
My plugin configuration from my pom.xml file looks like this:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.pkl.codegen.java.Main</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-o</argument>
                        <argument>generated</argument>
                        <argument>src/main/resources/config/ApplicationConfig.pkl</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pkl-lang</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pkl-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>0.27.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>

But when I run my tests they throw this error:
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. org.pkl.codegen.java.Main

Interestingly using Java on the command line works fine:
$ java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/pkl-lang/pkl-tools/0.27.0/pkl-tools-0.27.0.jar org.pkl.codegen.java.Main -o generated src/main/resources/config/ApplicationConfig.pkl

